# How do I extend the bars across the axis?

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts bar chart where the bars do not extend the entire width of the chart.  How do I correct this?

http://jsfiddle.net/brookssh/mtpc5tqa/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: "chartContainer",
        defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
        height: 595
    },
    title: {
        text: '18 York Road (Consumption/SqFt)',
        style: {
            color: '#484a4a',
            fontSize: '22px',
            fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Friday, August 21 2015 through Saturday, August 22 2015'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: "Test",
            style: {
                color: '#0063A2',
                fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'red', // Color value                            
            value: null, // Value of where the line will appear
            width: 2 // Width of the line    
        }],
        min: 0
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['9th Floor', '8th Floor', '7th Floor', '6th Floor', '5th Floor', '4th Floor', '3rd Floor', '25th Floor', '24th Floor', '23rd Floor', '22nd Floor', '21st Floor', '20th Floor', '19th Floor', '18th Floor', '17th Floor', '16th Floor', '15th Floor', '14th Floor', '13th Floor', '12th Floor', '11th Floor', '10th Floor'],
        title: {
        },
        type: 'category',
        plotBands: [{
            color: '#DDECFF',
            from: 1440176400000,
            to: 1440262800000
        }],
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'grey', // Color value                            
            dashStyle: "dash",
            value: null, // Value of where the line will appear
            width: 0 // Width of the line    
        }],
    }, {
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            enabled: false
        },
        lineWidth: 0,
    }],
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            colorByPoint: true
        },
        spline: {
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            animation: {
                duration: 1500
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 5,
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        yDecimals: 2,
        formatter: function () {
            return tooltipFormat(this.x, null, this.y, yAxisTitle);
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [0.01, 0.012, 0.014, 0.013, 0.015, 0.024, 0.019, 0.015, 0.014, 0.013, 0.011, 0.012, 0.015, 0.013, 0.014, 0.01, 0.015, 0.016, 0.021, 0.016, 0.018, 0.021, 0.008],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000',
            style: {
                fontSize: '10px',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `allowDecimals: false` in the y-axis, you are forcing the axis to extend to 1. As the longest bar value is only 0.024, this means the  bars will not extend the entire width of the chart.

Removing the line `allowDecimals: false` lets the axis automatically set to 0.03 and the bars to extend to most of the width of the chart.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/Lyascc3z/)

As Sebastian Bochan suggests, if you want further control over the positioning of the ticks you could use [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions) or a [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner). These would allow you to extend the longest bar to the full width of the chart if required.

Comment: Additionally you can use a [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions) / [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner)